# VBA Find and replace function - where to put the loop? MS Word

Tags: vba, loops, ms-word

I can't for the life of me work out where I need to put the loop within my find and replace function.

I have documents which have 3+ line breaks in a row. I'm writing a find and replace function which looks for 3 line breaks and replaces it with just 2 line breaks. I need to loop through this until only 2 line breaks remain.

See expected and actual results for a document example.

I've tried putting it within "With Selection.Find" but it doesn't work?

```
Private Function FindReplaceLineBreaks()
'
'
    Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
    Selection.Find.Replacement.ClearFormatting
    With Selection.Find
        .Text = "^p^p^p"
        .Replacement.Text = "^p^p"
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindContinue
        .Format = False
        .MatchCase = False
        .MatchWholeWord = False
        .MatchWildcards = False
        .MatchSoundsLike = False
        .MatchAllWordForms = False
    End With
    Selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
End Function


Document example:

Chapter 1
Linebreak
Linebreak
Linebreak
Linebreak
Linebreak
This is some text etc. etc.
Linebreak
Linebreak
Linebreak
Linebreak
Linebreak
Linebreak
Linebreak
Linebreak
Linebreak
Text

Expected:

Chapter 1
Linebreak
Linebreak
This is some text etc. etc.
Linebreak
Linebreak
Text
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest way to do this is to make the function recursive (the function recalls itself). Add this one line to the bottom of your function:

```
If (Selection.Find.Found = True) then call FindReplaceLineBreaks
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Private Function FindReplaceLineBreaks()
    with Selection.Find
        .ClearFormatting
        .Replacement.ClearFormatting
        .Text = "^p^p^p"
        .Replacement.Text = "^p^p"
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindContinue
        .Format = False
        .MatchCase = False
        .MatchWholeWord = False
        .MatchWildcards = False
        .MatchSoundsLike = False
        .MatchAllWordForms = False

        Do While .Execute(Replace:=wdReplaceAll)
        Loop

    End With

End Function
```